# How do I change the configuration of angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker dynamically from angular?

Tags: angularjs

```
data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#taskDateTo',
                              minView: 'day',
                              startView: 'day' }"
```

This is the code. If I change this JSON to a method call, it does not change the date picker configuration when the method returns different values.

Basically, I want to be able to change from day -> month -> year view based on the value selected in another combo box.

This description should be adequate to anybody familiar with the control. I did post a question on the git forum, which does not have the stack overflow police - somebody did answer. Changing the code to use a scope variable instead of method did not fix the issue.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [configureOn](https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker#configureon) option. Essentially, you  `$broadcast`  an event when you want the directive to re-read it's configuration.

Comment: Stack Overflow police prevents me from answering my own question. So, I will post the exact how to do on Github:

Comment: https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/401#issuecomment-339093056